# Как в Entity Framework 6 получить доступ к полям объекта, тип которого задан как дженерик?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Хочу создать метод наподобие

```
var doc = FindDocument<Накладная>(25);
```

чтобы искать документы любого типа по id.

Реализация например такая:

```
public T FindDocument<T>(long id)
{
    context.???.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DocumentID == id);
}
```

То как я могу это сделать?
Вроде в EF есть возможность обращаться к таблицам не явно через `context.DOCUMENTS.FirstOrDefault(...)`, а через `context.Set<T>`, но когда используются дженерики, то там нельзя задать условие `.DocumentID == id`, потому что он не знает о полях таблицы.

UPD: Накладная - это класс, сгенерированный EF'ом, т.е. "таблица" и она не имеет базового класса. Под каждый вид документа - Накладная, НалоговыйВычет и т.д. - отдельная таблица, но у них всех есть ID.

В обычной ситуации приходится писать:

```
context.Накладная.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == 25);
```

а мне нужно (если это возможно) вот так:

```
var doc = FindDocument<Накладная>(25);
```

поскольку поиск сопровождается еще дополнительной логикой, которую каждый раз копировать не хочется, и я мог бы ее спрятать в этот метод.

Comment: Ну вы в параметрах передавайте не id, а какой нить `Predicate<T>`

Comment: Пример не приведете? Предлагаете условие поиска передавать в параметре? Если да, то это не подходит. Смысл как раз в том, чтобы поместить условие поиска в метод, ибо оно везде одинаковое DocumentID == id, а передавать только id, через дженерик указывая тип документа, который нужно найти.

Comment: Если у вас поле везде одинаковое, то зачем вам просто Т? Указывайте общий базовый класс или интерфейс в параметрах обобщения.

Comment: Я наверное сформулировал не очень, дополнил вопрос. Базового класса нет, потому что Накладная - это сгенерированный EF'ом класс по таблице.

Comment: Ну вы можете использовать рефлексию, но имхо проще тогда под каждый класс свой метод написать.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, имеется интерфейс:

```
public interface IDocument
{
    long DocumentID { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда можно ваш метод записать так:

```
public T FindDocument<T>(long id)
    where T : class, IDocument
{
    return context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.DocumentID == id);
}
```

Обратите внимание на ограничение (constraint) `where`.

Сущность `Накладная` должна реализовывать этот интерфейс.

Comment: Вариант хороший, но что делать, если базового класса нет? Накладная - это класс, который сгенерировал EF по таблице БД.

Comment: @Shebbyman, добавьте partial класс

Comment: А без этого? Что-то приделывать к таблицам - неудобно. Функция должна быть максимально самодостаточной и не выдвигать дополнительных требований к таблицам.

Comment: @Shebbyman, даже если отбросить все вышесказанное об интерфейсах, функция уже выдвинула дополнительное требование - в классе должено быть свойство с конкретным именем. Чтобы функция не выдвигала дополнительных требований к таблицам, пользователю придется в параметрах функции передавать ссылку на поле, по которому надо фильтровать.

Answer (score 1):

Решение навеянное ответом отсюда: [EntityFramework 6 How to get identity-field with reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141955).

Получив имя свойства, мы можем сгенерировать LINQ выражение динамически:

```cs
public T FindDocument<T>(long id) where T : class {
    ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    ObjectSet<T> set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    ParameterExpression objParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");
    Expression body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(objParam, GetEntityKey(set)), Expression.Constant(id));
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, objParam);
    return set.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
static string GetEntityKey<T>(ObjectSet<T> set) where T : class {
    if(set.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Count != 1) {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    return set.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers[0].Name;
}
```